# Why don't we use R.id instead of R.layout while inflating layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b,container,false);
View v = findViewById(R.id.fragB);
```

i want to know when to use

```
R.id.fragB
```

and when to use

```
R.layout.fragment_b.
```

Can't we use

```
R.id.fragB
```

in place of

```
R.layout.fragment_b
```

in first statement.

Comment: you can't inflate the id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All references under `R.layout` refer to your layout files themselves. For example, if you define the layout for your fragment in `fragment_b.xml`, then `R.layout.fragment_b` is a way for the framework to reference that file.

References under `R.id` are identifiers. They could be identifiers for views in a layout, or they could be just generic identifiers that you create for other purposes.

Your layout XML might start with a root View that has an ID, but it also might not. Your layout XML can also contain views with many different IDs. Thus the two are not interchangeable.